# How to show PDF on UI using RESTful/ajax/js using form input from UI?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, pdf

I am trying to show a PDF report on UI for RESTful Services using javascript and ajax. It is working fine for single input but for multiple inputs using form from the UI which I later change to JSON object it is not showing PDF in right format. I have already checked service using POSTMAN which is working fine (downloads PDF).

Below is the code written in JAVA for service.

```
 @POST
  @Path("/CustomizedReport")
  @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
  @Produces("application/pdf")
  public Response getCustomizedReport(SubscriberCriteriaTool sct) throws ParseException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    new CustomizedReport().aaGeneratePdf(outputStream, sct);
    byte[] bytes = outputStream.toByteArray();
    DataSource dataSource = new ByteArrayDataSource(bytes, "application/pdf");
    ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok(dataSource);
    response.header("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=CustomizedReport.pdf");
    return response.build();
  }
```

Below is the function in javascript.

```
function generateCustomizedReport() {
    console.log('generateCustomizedReport');
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        contentType : 'application/json',
        url : 'http://localhost:8080/Morpheus/api/reports/CustomizedReport',
        data : formToJSONReport(),
        success : function(response) { 
                    document.write(response);

        },
        error : function(error, status) {
            window.alert("Problem retrieving PDF.\nThe error status is: " + error);
        }
    });
}
```

Below is the function to change form to JSON. Right now it is hard coded, but plan to take the input from UI once it works. It is the exact same string I used to check on POSTMAN which is giving the right result(downloads PDF).

```
function formToJSONReport() {
    return JSON.stringify({
        "fromDate" : "10/01/2014",
        "rateCenter" : "HUNTINGTON",
        "status" : "SUCCESSFUL",
        "toDate" : "11/01/2014",
        "group" : "Third"

    });
}
```

This is the PDF text I am getting on UI (Unable to post snapshot since I am new on stackoverflow).

%PDF-1.4 %���� 1 0 obj <>stream ����ExifII*��Ducky7���http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/ ��!Adobed�   B�M@D]���       ##########

Thank you in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your response is file stream bytes, we can't show the file by writing the bytes directly on to document, but we can download the stream with specified content-type(here application/pdf) using iframe or new-window (or another Technic attaching a form by targeting to iframe or _blank i.e., response will open in new window new window).

Try by changing your success function as below

```
    success : function(response) {
            //This double pass request Technic is to download the file stream via iframe.
            $("<iframe>").attr("src", 'http://localhost:8080/Morpheus/api/reports/CustomizedReport')
            //.hide()//hide it while download
            .appendTo("body");

            //OR you can try with popup window
            //window.open('http://localhost:8080/Morpheus/api/reports/CustomizedReport')
    }
```

**Usually we write two actions in controller.**

1. For Validate Request and return the response with valid-token (encrypted value of some key and timestamp)
2. To get the file through iframe(or new window) with above valid-token that received in the response  of the first request success(or done) callback.